# Create setup.exe with Installshield

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, installshield

I developed a WPF system with a fingerprint reader.Now I'm going to make setup file with  Installshield. So developed system required drivers of fingerprint reader, what I need is develop a setup file that also installs drvers for the target machine simultaneously.

Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this. Also you can add custom action that executes arbitrary custom dll code so you can do additional setup if needed.

If you need to add custom action you need to go to custom actions and sequences and add the action there.

Also you can execute an executable from an action - this executable could be the driver's installer.

There are also some other options depending on your scenario and some are discussed [here](http://forum.installsite.net/index.php?showtopic=15898).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks quick respond, Can u show me the path? How Can I achieve this?

Comment: I have added a more detailed response. If you have other questions please ask. I have had myself quite hard time finding install shield documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> > Can I achieve this?

Yes

[Installing Device Drivers](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield17helplib/Langref_Installing_Drivers.htm)

[Device Driver Wizard](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield17helplib/DeviceDriverWizard.htm)

If that does not work, you can write Custom Action.